# Extract variable names and values using REGEX in Python from a text file

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read a large text file, containing variable names and corresponding values (see below for small example). Names are all upper case and the value is usually separated by a periods and whitespaces, but if the variable name is too long it is separated by only whitespaces.

```
WATER DEPTH ..........     20.00 M      TENSION AT TOUCHDOWN .    382.47 KN  

TOUCHDOWN X-COORD. ...   -206.75 M      BOTTOM SLOPE ANGLE ...     0.000 DEG 

PROJECTED SPAN LENGTH     166.74 M      PIPE LENGTH GAIN .....      1.72 M
```

I am able to find the values using the following expression:

```
line = '   PROJECTED SPAN LENGTH     166.74 M      PIPE LENGTH GAIN .....      1.72 M   \n'
re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", line):
['166.74', '1.72']
```

But when I try to extract the variable names, using below expression  I have leading and trailing whitespaces which I would like to leave out.

```
re.findall('(?<=\s.)[A-Z\s]+', line)
[' PROJECTED SPAN LENGTH     ', '      PIPE LENGTH GAIN ', '    ', '   \n']
```

I believe it should have something like ^\s, but I can't get it to work. 
When successful I'd like to store the data in a dataframe, having the variable names as indices and the values as column.

Comment: Use  `r'[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression along with `re.finditer()`:

```
(?P<category>[A-Z][A-Z- ]+[A-Z])
[. ]+
(?P<value>-?\d[.\d]+)\ 
(?P<unit>M|DEG|KN)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wW2tL0/3).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?P<category>[A-Z][A-Z- ]+[A-Z])
    [. ]+
    (?P<value>-?\d[.\d]+)\ 
    (?P<unit>M|DEG|KN)
''', re.VERBOSE)

string = '''
WATER DEPTH ..........     20.00 M      TENSION AT TOUCHDOWN .    382.47 KN  

TOUCHDOWN X-COORD. ...   -206.75 M      BOTTOM SLOPE ANGLE ...     0.000 DEG 

PROJECTED SPAN LENGTH     166.74 M      PIPE LENGTH GAIN .....      1.72 M  
'''

matches = [(m.group('category'), m.group('value'), m.group('unit')) \
            for m in rx.finditer(string)]
print(matches)
# [('WATER DEPTH', '20.00', 'M'), ('TENSION AT TOUCHDOWN', '382.47', 'KN'), ('TOUCHDOWN X-COORD', '-206.75', 'M'), ('BOTTOM SLOPE ANGLE', '0.000', 'DEG'), ('PROJECTED SPAN LENGTH', '166.74', 'M'), ('PIPE LENGTH GAIN', '1.72', 'M')]
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/4JNIx1).

Comment: Thanks Jan, this is a very neat solution and regex101.com is also pretty handy. As such, I have taken the liberty to pose another question to you for which I would like to give the link to the problem [link] https://regex101.com/r/nK3hN6/1 In my previous question I had only posted a section of the text to analyze, but there are some more lines, with which I have some difficulty as well. Lines with no units for example. Thanks in advance

Comment: @EmielT: https://regex101.com/r/nK3hN6/2 (make the last group optional and put the longest alternatives first.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! It has given me at least a bit more insight in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[A-Z]{2,}(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*`

`[A-Z]{2,}` looks for uppercase words at least 2 in length

`(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*` is a capture group for if there are multiple words in the label

**EDIT**

To handle the case in your comment I'd recommend:

```
[A-Z-\/]{2,}(?:\s*[A-Z-\/]+(?:\.)*)*
```

just make sure there is at least one space after the last period in `R.O.W.` and before the `...`

`[A-Z-\/]{2,}` will check for uppercase letters, -, and / of 2 length or greater

`(?:\s*[A-Z-\/]+(?:\.)*)*` is a capture group for for multiple words and/or words with periods in them

Comment: Thanks depperm, this works rather well. However, for the seond last row _TOUCHDOWN X-COORD._ is being split into _TOUCHDOWN_ and _COORD_.  Ok, this can be fixed by escaping the character in non-capture group. However in the text file the following may also occur: WEIGHT/LENGTH IN AIR .   1301.00 N/M    YIELD STRESS .........    241.00 MPA or BARGE HEADING ........     0.000 DEG    OFFSET FROM R.O.W. ...      0.00 M. Here R.O.W. for example is not found, which I believe can be caught by using a lookbehind/lookahead statement. Could you please advise on how to implement this as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to take out leading/trailing white space, you can use the `.strip()` method.

[Python String strip](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm)

```
stripped_values = [raw.strip() for raw in re.findall('(?<=\s.)[A-Z\s]+', line)]
```